# Send JSON message to Azure Queue storage

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am using `azure-storage` node module. 
I would like to send JSON on my queue and get it into my queue on azure function.

I send message in queue. I stringify my message to put in queue.

```js
// This is my service who send message to queue via node lib azure-storage
       const queueMsg = {
              userId,
              token: tokenNotif
            };
            queueSvc.createMessage(Config.REGISTRATION_FCM_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE, JSON.stringify(queueMsg), (err) => {
              if (!error) {
                this._logger.info(`User ${userId} has register this push notification token`);
                resolve(true);

              } else {
                reject(false);
              }
            });
```

And in the queue function i have an error because the function think isn't a string and push the message text on xx-queue-poison
`{&quot;userId&quot;:&quot;a6c8a103-dacc-4b15-bffd-60693105f131&quot;,&quot;token&quot;:&quot;xxxx&quot;}`

I don't know why the quote is replaced by ASCII code on queue ?

I have tested something else!
From my service i call a Http Azure function, and this function call the Queue Storage and it's work by this way :s ..

The HttpTrigger function call queue
`context.bindings.notificationQueue = [{ userId: name, token }];`

And queue received data
`` context.log(`Received userId ${queueItem.userId} :: ${queueItem.token}`); ``

Why by using HttpTrigger function to QueueTrigger function it's working, but when i am using the lib "azure-storage" is not working ?

Thx

Comment: I found ! 
Instead of stringify the object i convert it into b64.
`Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(queueMsg)).toString('base64')` and it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why the quote is replaced by ASCII code on queue ?

Basically the SDK is converting the string message to make it XML safe. If you look at the code in the SDK, by default it uses `TextXmlQueueMessageEncoder` as the message encoder. The `encode` function replaces `"` with `&quot;` to make it XML safe.

From the SDK code (partial code snippets):

```
QueueService.prototype.createMessage = function (queue, messageText, optionsOrCallback, callback) {
  var userOptions;
  azureutil.normalizeArgs(optionsOrCallback, callback, function (o, c) { userOptions = o; callback = c; });

  validate.validateArgs('createMessage', function (v) {
    v.string(queue, 'queue');
    v.queueNameIsValid(queue);
    v.callback(callback);
  });

  var xmlMessageDescriptor = QueueMessageResult.serialize(messageText, this.messageEncoder);
```

---

```
function TextXmlQueueMessageEncoder(){
}
util.inherits(TextXmlQueueMessageEncoder, QueueMessageEncoder);

/**
 * Encode utf-8 string by escaping the xml markup characters.
 * @this TextXmlQueueMessageEncoder
 * 
 * @param   {string}    [input]               The target to be encoded.
 * 
 * @return {string}
 */
TextXmlQueueMessageEncoder.prototype.encode = function(input){
  return input.replace(/&/gm, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</gm, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/gm, '&gt;')
    .replace(/"/gm, '&quot;')
    .replace(/'/gm, '&apos;');
};
```

One possible solution would be to convert the string to a base64 encoded string as you suggested. However if you're using the SDK to retrieve the messages, you should not see these `&quot;` in your message body as the SDK takes care of decoding the message.